# Как сравнить две строки типа std::string

Tags: c++

Имеются две переменные типа `string`.
Подскажите методы их сравнения.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Хм... Просто взять и сравнить:

```
std::string a = "Hello", b = "World";
...
a < b;
a > b;
a == b;
a != b;
```

Answer (score 3):

Функция strcmp имеет прототип:

```
int strcmp(const char* str1, const char* str2);
```

После сравнения строк str1 и str2 данная функция возвратит целое значение:

```
<0 , если str1 < str2
=0 , если str1 = str2
>0 , если str1 > str2
```

Эта функция производит сравнение, различая прописные и строчные буквы

Пример:

```
char s1[]="Hello";
char s2[]="HeLlo";
int k=strcmp(s1,s2);
cout<< k;
```

В результате, на экран будет выведено: 32. Т.к. код символа l = 108, а код символа L = 76. 108-76=32.

Взято от [сюда](http://www.prostocpp.narod.ru/compare_of_strings.html)

Comment: Функция `strcmp` гарантирует только знак возвращенного значения, но не дает никакой гарантии на тему того, какое *именно* значение будет возвращено. Поэтому утверждать, что в данном примере будет возвращено именно `32` нельзя.

Comment: Вопрос вроде как по C++ в первую очередь. А вы про сишные строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool check;
    cout << "Type a text: ";
    string text;
    getline(cin, text);
    cout << "Type else text: ";
    string text2;
    getline(cin,text2);
    vector <char>res2(text2.begin(), text2.end());
    vector <char> res(text.begin(), text.end());
    for(auto i=res.begin();i<res.end(); ++i){
        while(isupper(*i)){
                *i=tolower(*i);
            }
        for(auto j=res2.begin(); j<res2.end();++j){
            while(isupper(*j)){
                *j=tolower(*j);
            }
            if(*i == *j){
                check=true;
            }else{
                check =false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(check ==false){
        cout << "first string differ from second one\n";
    }else{
        cout << "First string is the same as second\n";
    }
    cout << check;
return 0;
}
```